# Cannot save file

Tags: front-end, bugs, files-and-directories, windows, localization

Hello I have a problem in saving files in Mathematica. I can't save not only notebooks but also figures. When I choose to save the notebook it open a window that says:

> Mathematica could not find enough disk space to save the file `C:\Users\Διονύσης\Documents\science\mathematica\Untitled-1.nb`.  The file was left unchanged.  The disk is full, or if you are using a file server you may have reached your disk space quota.

Although I have notebook saved from a friend. I can save on it. When I want to use it i simply copy-paste it, delete the code, wright mine and then I can save it without any problem. But still I cannot save figures. To save them I can only copy-paste them to Word from where I can save them as figures.

If anyone could tell me the source of my problem it would be helpfull! Thank you very much!

Comment: I think the problem is that there is a greek folder in the path, try saving on the root of the drive, c:\, or to another drive to see if this is the problem.

Comment: That was the problem! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Τίποτα! Μάλλον μονο οι Έλληνες το έχουν αυτο το πρόβλημα ;)

Comment: I'm torn between voting to close (because we can't do anything about it) or leaving it open as a cautionary tale for others. I see no good reason why *Mathematica* should encounter problems here and the error message is highly misleading.

Comment: @Oleksandr, maybe tag this as a bug, contingent on someone else confirming that "weird" folders trigger this behavior.

Comment: @J.M. good suggestion. I'm going to go ahead and add the [tag:bugs] tag since the behavior is clearly not right (although it's not entirely clear to me whether this may be a Windows-specific problem). If anyone disagrees, they're free to remove it.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Sorry, I didn't realize it was you who added the bugs tag (I should pay more attention... I thought it was posted like that). This is a common problem on Windows: many programs don't support Unicode paths. If the OP's locale is set to Greek, it should work, otherwise there's a chance it won't.(It was the same for me: I can't use őű in path names if I have the locale set to English in WinXP, and I also can't use Chinese characters.Once I got into trouble because I created a chinese-named dropbox folder on a Chinese computer, and I couldn't open Mathematica files within it on my own

Comment: @Szabolcs FWIW it hates my name as well (Олександр) regardless of the fact that other programs do not have any difficulties (and nor should they). The reason why I suggested that it might be Windows-specific is because of the particular way in which Unicode characters are (needlessly?) escaped by *Mathematica*, i.e. by adding a ``\``, which also happens to be a Windows path element. If these characters were simply left alone then presumably the problem would not arise. I do think this is a bug, albeit perhaps not one that is very likely to get fixed.

Comment: @OleksandrR. It is Windows specific, but the reason is different: it most likely uses the non-unicode version of the Windows API calls.  They come in two flavour, and the unicode ones have a W suffix (for Wide, i.e. two-byte UTF-16).  The fix would be to use the W-calls.  I guess it's worth a complaint to support as in 2013 programs should not have trouble with Unicode.  I agree we shouldn't close this question, it can be confusing when this happens.  Even more confusing when it happens only on one computer (the one with the non-Greek locale)

Comment: @Szabolcs that is a very good guess (actually I had forgotten about that possibility, as the A-functions are supposed to be obsolete) but it turns out not to be correct. I checked with Process Monitor and indeed `CreateFileW` is used but *Mathematica*'s escaped string is being passed to it... my name is turned into ``\:041e\:043b\:0435\:043a\:0441\:0430\:043d\:0434\:0440`` which of course prompts `CreateFile` to return `ERROR_INVALID_NAME`. I guess it does not happen on localized Windows only because characters in the system code page are not escaped.

Comment: @Szabolcs just for completeness I should add that after querying the file's attributes (if it exists) using `CreateFileW`, the FE then attempts to use `CreateFileA` to actually create or overwrite the file (apparently it cannot tell the difference between `ERROR_INVALID_NAME` and `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` produced as a result of the first call and so does not give up sooner, which suggests inadequate error handling in this routine). It uses the same (escaped) filename either way, though, which is what causes `CreateFile` to fail (i.e. if `CreateFileW` would have been used, it would still fail).

Comment: @OleksandrR. Wow, that's clearly a bug!  You should ping support@wolfram.com.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Mathematica uses the standard library for file APIs.  Whether CreateFileA or CreateFileW gets called is an implementational detail of the VC++ standard library.  It is true that we are using the non-widechar version of the standard library file functions, which is, of course, the cause of the problem.  In answer as to why on earth we would still, in 2013, be doing this, I can only say that it's something I certainly would have done had I more resources, but I'm always forced to choose between shipping one thing or another (and that choice has many outside influences).

Comment: Sometimes dragging the legacy of the way we did things 15 years ago around in the code sucks.  I recently spent nearly two months digging one of those legacy things out of the system (also to do with Unicode, but with fonts instead of files).  We'll fix this one, too, but I just can't yet make a guarantee as to when.

Comment: @JohnFultz thanks for the information. Doesn't sound like a trade-off one would like to have to make, that's for sure! Given that it's consistent and there's a simple workaround, this behavior seems tolerable enough and probably deserves a low priority if there are more important issues to be fixed elsewhere.

Comment: I just had the same error message when using CDFDeploy and no greek or strange characters. I solved it by applying ExpandFileName. It appears that relative paths make CDFDeploy report that the disk is full! (Win7, MMA 11.1)